# Is it possible to execute a method before and after all tests in the assembly?

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

I would like to built an nunit project for selenium ui automation. I would like to sign in to the site before running all tests (all of them) and to close the browser after running all tests (all of them).

I can't use the SetUp since it related to fixtures and I want to do it before and after everything.

Do you know who to execute it?

---

I'm familiar with the SetUp and TearDown attribute.
Let me explain it again.

I need some logic to be executed before all tests from all fixtures starts (AKA - First test in the entire assembly) and also some logic to be executed after all tests from all fixtures ended (AKA - Last test in the entire assembly).

Answer (score 64):

If all your test fixtures are within the same namespace then you can use the `[SetUpFixture]` attribute to mark a class as the global setup and teardown. You can then put all your login/logout functionality in there.

**NUNIT 2.x**

```
namespace MyNamespace.Tests
{
    using System;
    using NUnit.Framework;

    [SetUpFixture]
    public class TestsSetupClass
    {
        [SetUp]
        public void GlobalSetup()
        {
            // Do login here.
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void GlobalTeardown()
        {
            // Do logout here
        }
    }
}
```

See:
http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=setupFixture&r=2.4

**NUNIT 3.x**

```
namespace MyNamespace.Tests
{
    using System;
    using NUnit.Framework;

    [SetUpFixture]
    public class TestsSetupClass
    {
        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public void GlobalSetup()
        {
            // Do login here.
        }

        [OneTimeTearDown]
        public void GlobalTeardown()
        {
            // Do logout here
        }
    }
}
```

See:
https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/SetUpFixture-Attribute

Comment: In NUnit 3.x its now `[OneTimeSetUp]` and `[OneTimeTearDown]`

Answer (score 12):

Sure.  That's what the `[TestSetUp]` and `[TearDown]` attributes are for.  Don't confuse them with `[TestFixtureSetUp]` and `[TestFixtureTearDown]`, which are executed before the first test and after the last.

Answer (score 3):

Before executing each test cases `[SetUp]` section will executed

after completed the execution of each test cases `[TearDown]` section will executed.

if we want to initialize variables we often write in `[SetUp]` section like  a constructor

if we want to dispose any object we often write in `[TearDown]` section

```
    [SetUp]
    protected void SetUp()
    {
             //initialize objects
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
       //dispose objects
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing in `nunit` is the [SetupFixture](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=setupFixture&r=2.5.5) attribute, which allows you to tag a class to do setup/teardown for all test fixtures in a namespace;

> The SetUp method in a SetUpFixture is executed once before any of the fixtures contained in its namespace. The TearDown method is executed once after all the fixtures have completed execution.